# How cpu access bits?

Tags: memory, hardware

I know that base address and its length of are stored.I want to know how its circuitry access bits and stop accessing after particular stored length? Are there any some kind counter used to access next bytes?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking. This question could refer to several CPU features at the moment. A bit more detail please. Please take the tour in the help center to help you ask good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Computer memory is arranged in words, each word containing 8, 16, 32, or more bits, depending on the processor.  When the CPU accesses memory, it gets one full word - there is no need to count individual bits.